# MySQL Query returns the Object rather than Array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, database

I'm trying to get the Array so i can loop it through and get the category_id from it. Its output is in Odd behavior, 1st it comes in Public Row, then Public Rows, and then Num Rows. I'm not able to loop to these object as the loop code terminated in the 1st Row only and not going further in Rows. Basically, the output query returns like this:

```
array (size=3)
  'row' => 
    array (size=2)
      'product_id' => string '50' (length=2)
      'category_id' => string '20' (length=2)
  'rows' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'product_id' => string '50' (length=2)
          'category_id' => string '20' (length=2)
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          'product_id' => string '50' (length=2)
          'category_id' => string '28' (length=2)
  'num_rows' => int 2
```

I'm trying to get the simple array so i can loop it dynamically and get the desired output.
Here's my PHP code:

```
$categories = (array)$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX ."product_to_category WHERE product_id=50");
var_dump($categories);
```

However I've converted the Object into Array by prefixing (array) to the query but it doesn't worked for me as its still in object. Please suggest me as its taking too much time to settle this problem????

I DON'T KNOW WHY THIS IS COMING IN OBJECT?? BUT I GOT THE SOLUTION'S USING 
    var_dump($categories['rows']);

If anybody know the exact solution your help might be acceptable.

Comment: Are you using any framework? like codeigniter etc? show me your definition of query function

Answer (score 0):

Which framework you are  using ?? if you arr using Simple PHP look at this function 
 [mysql_fetch_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Comment: I'm using Opencart, i've used mysql_fetch_array but it doesn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

return all the data in an array using function `mysql_fetch_array`

```
$categories = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX ."product_to_category WHERE product_id=50");
var_dump(mysql_fetch_array($categories));
```

Font: https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array

Comment: ITS NOT WORKING, BASICALLY WHY THIS TYPE OF OUTPUT IS COMING. Basically i want to remove the 1st array, Num Rows from the above code i posted. It terminates after the 1st array, I've used several queries which return simple array like this: array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'product_id' => string '50' (length=2)
          'category_id' => string '20' (length=2)
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          'product_id' => string '50' (length=2)
          'category_id' => string '28' (length=2)